# how to verify AWS instance have static IP or Not

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip

I have set up one AWS windows instance. As per my requirement, I need static IP. So I set up one elastic IP and assign those IP to Windows instance. My problem is I'm not able to verify that elastic IP is assigned to Windows instance or not. Any way to verify that elastic Ip is assigned or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have AWS command line client properly configured, this command:

`aws ec2 describe-addresses --query "Addresses[].[InstanceId, PublicIp]" --output table`

Will show you a table with each Elastic IP association. If an IP is not attached will show the `InstanceId` empty.

Answer (score 2):

I have found my answer

There are two ways for this:
1) You can Navigate to Elastic IP Console and click on any IP There and see the fourth TAB as Instance ID, this will confirm that what Instance is associated with the Elastic IP.

2) Look at Instance Description and see Public IP Tab if it IP With Hyperlink then it is Elastic IP.